# Filehandle for Output from System Command in Perl

Tags: perl, ipc, pipe, stdio, filehandle

Is there a filehandle/handle for the output of a system command I execute in Perl?

Answer (score 12):

Here's an example of establishing pipes between your script and other commands, using the 3-argument form of [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

```
open(my $incoming_pipe, '-|', 'ls -l')             or die $!;
open(my $outgoing_pipe, '|-', "grep -v '[02468]'") or die $!;

my @listing = <$incoming_pipe>;          # Lines from output of ls -l
print $outgoing_pipe "$_\n" for 1 .. 50; # 1 3 5 7 9 11 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a pipe like this:

```
open(my $pipe, "ls|") or die "Cannot open process: $!";
while (<$pipe>) {
    print;
}
```

See the documentation for [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) for more information, and [`perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) for a complete description of pipe operation.

Comment: Two-arg `open` is old and crufty (and potentially dangerous). [Use the three-arg version instead](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html)